# iframe history.length query

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have been playing around with the `history.length` property in JavaScript.

However, I have come across a bit of a problem I don't understand.

On my localhost machine I have Page A and Page B that both have one line of script being:

```
document.write("Number of URLs in history list: " + history.length);
```

I opened a browser tab loaded Page A which said URL value was 1 (being first page opened) and I then entered Page B URL and the number of URL value changed to 2. Thats fine.

Tried then doing the same using iframes (opening page A and then changing to page B) but the `history.length` value stays at 1 not 2?

Any ideas? Both pages are on same origin so should not a problem accessing `DOM` of `iframe`s just incorrect value being returned? Does the iframes history.lenght value have to be got like `document.getElementById('myframe').history.lenght`

Answer (score 2):

iframe is treated as a new 'session'... so that it won't count it for the browser history

Comment: Ok, I see I thought maybe I was accessing the history object for the iframe wrong maybe access it like this instead document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.history.length ?

Comment: I am sure you can just open one page in iframe store the history.lenght value in variable, change the src to another page and compare the variables if different?

Comment: sure... than you would have to track your own history... not sure if you'd want that :)

Comment: how do I access the iframe property of history.lenght? I keep getting value 1 when loading one iframe with src Page A, storing history.lenght value in variable then changing the same iframes src to Page B? I guess I am accessing the wrong hsitory.lenght should it not be something like document.getElementById('myframe').history.lenght ? But that throws an error?